# Checkbox if in 2 mysql queries using php

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have 2 mysql queries, each lists a range of companies. 1 a complete list and 1 a shorter list.

I am displaying them in a bulleted list and if the same company is in both queries, I would like to check the related checkbox next to it.

At the moment, I can display the complete list no problem, and then check the first one that is in both lists, but it won't check any more that are repeated in both lists.

I have tried while statements, foreach statements and also in_array, but think I must be missing something. Hoping someone can show me the error of my ways.

```
    $companysolicitors = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM companyselected WHERE companyid='$companyid'");
$companysolicitor = mysql_fetch_array( $companysolicitors );


$mainquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company”);
while($listcompanies = mysql_fetch_array($mainquery)) {


echo  "<input name=‘companies[]' type='checkbox' id='".$listcompanies['companyid']."' data-role='none' value='".$listcompanies['companyid']."’";

    foreach ($companysolicitor as $i) { if ($i == $listcompanies['companyid']) { echo ' checked'; } }

echo  "><label for='".$listcompanies['companyid']."'><span></span>".$listcompanies['companyname']."</label>”;

}
```

Comment: You can use `array_intersect` to catch those, what is in both.

Comment: There is an 'id' for each company in both, and the $listcompanies one also contains the company name. Not familiar with array_intersect, how could I used that in relation to checking a checkbox?

Comment: i think u have an error in comaprision // if ($i == $listcompanies['companyid']), here $i has an array of values and not a company id....

Comment: Thank you V Arun, yes I think you are right, and I think this is what Rana is showing in his answer below with his solution, but I still can't get more than 1 checkbox ticked. It's like the array doesn't contain all the data.

Answer (score 0):

from first query just return for eg cmp_id

like

`$companysolicitors = mysql_query("SELECT cmp_id FROM companyselected WHERE companyid='$companyid'");
$companysolicitor = mysql_fetch_array( $companysolicitors );`

now it should return
array(1,3,8,...) //this just an example

Now your second query is correct

```
        $mainquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company");
            while($listcompanies = mysql_fetch_array($mainquery)) {
                if(in_array($listcompanies['companyid'], $companysolicitor)){
                    $checked = 'checked="checked"';
                }else{
                    $checked = null;
                }
            echo  "<input name=‘companies[]' type='checkbox' id='".$listcompanies['companyid']."' data-role='none' value='".$listcompanies['companyid']."' $checked/><label for='".$listcompanies['companyid']."'><span></span>".$listcompanies['companyname']."</label>";

        }
```

Comment: Hi Rana. I have just tried your code, and it gives me the same problem. It 'ticks' the first checkbox that it should, but then nothing else.

Comment: If I make my own array, i.e. $companysolicitor = array("Smith", "John", "Doe"); then this seems to work ok, so then does this suggest that the mysql query is wrong? But it looks fine to me, and on checking the database there is more than 1 item selected, any ideas at all?

Comment: So it appears that my code and your code are almost correct, what I was missing was that I needed to turn the first query into array so that the 'in_array" statement could iterate over the whole array and not just the first item which was made by the mysql_fetch_array statement. So, the following fixed my problem: 

`code` 
$companysolicitor = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($companysolicitors)) {
    $companysolicitor[] = $row['cmp_id'];
}
`code`

Comment: sry for late reply do you need more help or you figure out the problem ?

Comment: Hi Rana. Sorry no I am now ok. You solution gave me the same problem I was already experiencing, but after further trial and error, I found that the first mysql query needed to be turned into an array of all the results, which it wasn't (I hadn't realised), once I did this it was all ok.